# Как кэшировать отдельные файлы на очень долго

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, framework

Для эффективной загрузки сайта (по рекомендациям гугл) я решил использовать кэширование. В .htaccess стоят типы файлов и время на которое необходимо их кэшировать. Но файлы js например некоторые нужно кэшировать на ооочень долго а некоторые всего на пару часов. Например огромная библиотека может грузится весьма долго, она в принципе вряд ли будет изменяться по этому её надо сохранить например на пару лет.

Подскажите как кэшировать отдельные файлы напрмиер /js/jquery.js а остальные js оставить так как есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

самый простой способ - добавлять в src к js версию файла.

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js?v=1"></script>
```

При изменении скрипта номер версии нужно изменить. Так как путь изменился, браузер будет вынужден загрузить его снова.

Если используется сборщик, например webpack, это можно автоматизировать

Comment: Через .htaccess так сделать нельзя?

Comment: @DmitryDevelop ну как вариант написать точнее FilesMatch, включить туда конкретные имена файлов, если не хочется заморачиваться